# Carry the last value forward for items no longer updated in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL server with accumulated returns over time for multiple securities.

The table looks like this:

```
report_date / security_id / return_usd
---------------------------------------
2016-02-21  / security_a   /  2.0 
2016-02-22  / security_a   / -1.2
2016-02-23  / security_a   / -2.7
2016-02-21  / security_b   /  5.2
```

The problem is that the accumulated return disappears for securities which have been sold or are matured (security b as an example above).

I need to continue to carry the last value (return_usd) forward for these securities as in the example below:

```
report_date / security_id / return_usd
---------------------------------------
2016-02-21  / security_a   /  2.0 
2016-02-22  / security_a   / -1.2
2016-02-23  / security_a   / -2.7
2016-02-21  / security_b   /  5.2  
2016-02-22  / security_b   /  5.2
2016-02-23  / security_b   /  5.2
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to figure it out myself so it would be much appreciated if anyone could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want a row for all securities and dates, and then to carry forward the sum.  You can generate the rows using `CROSS JOIN`.  Then, in SQL Server 2012+, you can use `LAG()`:

```
select d.report_date, s.security_id,
       coalesce(t.return_usd,
                lag(t.return_usd) over (partition by s.security_id
                                        order by (case when t.return_usd is not null then 1 else 2 end), d.report_date
                                       )
               ) as return_usd
from (select distinct report_date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct security_id from t) s left join
     t
     on t.report_date = d.report_date and t.security_id = s.security_id;
```

Note:  This fills in any `NULL` value with the previous non-`NULL` value.  If you have no gaps before the end, then this should be what you want.

EDIT:

This can also be written using `outer apply` or a correlated subquery:

```
select d.report_date, s.security_id,
       (select top 1 t.return_usd
        from t
        where t.report_date <= d.report_date and t.security_id = d.security_id and
              t.return_usd is not null
        order by t.report_date desc
       ) as return_usd
from (select distinct report_date from t) d cross join
     (select distinct security_id from t) s left join
     t
     on t.report_date = d.report_date and t.security_id = s.security_id;
```

This will work on earlier (supported) versions of SQL Server.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. However, I think it should be s.security_id and not d.security_id in the second solution, right?

Comment: am i missing something?  it seems like you're only going to pull the last value forward.  So if there's 2 days in a row without data (null) the second day will carry forward the previous null.

Comment: @FistOfFury . . . Yes, you are missing something either `ignore nulls` or `t.return_usd is not null` depending on the query you are looking at.